# Sitecore media field and icon is broken after unpublishing sitecore media item. How to handle this?

Tags: sitecore-client

Sitecore media field and icon is broken after unpublishing sitecore media item. How to handle this?

We are using Sitecore 9.3

Below is the stacktrace error.

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: delta]
   System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan delta) +193
   System.Web.HttpCachePolicyWrapper.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan delta) +15
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.SendMediaHeaders(Media media, HttpContextBase context) +467
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context, MediaRequest request, Media media) +357
   Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +57
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +884
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +232
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +100
```

[image]

Comment: What is the full exception stack trace? Can you check in logs?

Comment: it is too long and not letting me add here. I am adding it in question

Comment: I would check this field in sitecore database browser. We had once corrupted field and had to transfer item from web back to master to fix it. Check log in log.txt in your app_data folder or if no access to server then using desktop mode, reporting tools and log viewer. Also maybe try to reset field button too.

Comment: Any luck on solving this? i am facing the same issue.